# Redoublement du h en français

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe, arabe

J'ai lu à plusieurs endroits que la lettre *h* ne se redouble jamais en français. En bouquinant à la bibliothèque l'autre jour je suis tombé sur un livre qui disait cela et Bernard Pivot en était l'un des coauteurs. Malheureusement, je ne me rappelle plus du titre de l'ouvrage. La seule chose dont je me souvienne est qu'il était très coloré.

Bref, voici donc ma question : les mots « wahhabisme » et « wahhabite » ne sont-ils pas deux contre-exemples à cette supposée règle ?

Comment: Comme l'a dit fauve, il s'agit ici d'une "transcription" d'un terme arabe. Même si ce mot est utilisé en français, il ne fait pas parti à proprement parler de la "langue française".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Au risque d’être quelque peut hors sujet (mais il le faut dans ce cas particulier) c’est la transcription « wahhabisme » que je remet en cause car, lorsque l’on transcrit de l’arabe au français on ne double une consonne que lorsqu’elle est géminée en arabe avec la diacritique de la [šadda](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadda#.C5.A0adda). Or, le mot arabe *الوهابية* dont est dérrivé *wahhabite* ne contient pas de telle diacritique mais une consonne longue qui ne se transcrit usuellement pas par un doublement de la lettre latine mais par la suscription d’un macron. Ainsi, j’aurais plutôt parlé de *wah̄abisme* personnellement. Mais bon, tel n’est pas l’usage consacré.